# Subversion: blame for past revision

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I love Subversion's blame operation (which shows for each line in the source file the commit that last changed it). Alas, we recently reformatted our entire source code, and now blame just shows that every line was last modified by this commit.

Can I somehow instruct blame to show me when the line was last changed before that commit? Bonus points if I can do it without leaving eclipse (we use subclipse).

I tried switching the working copy to a revision prior to the reformat, and do "show annotation" there, but that still shows every line last modified by the reformat ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

God I *am* slow today. At the bottom of the dialog that "Show Annotate" pops up is the setting "To revision". Setting that to the last revision prior to the reformat performs as expected, i.e. blame reports the commits before the reformat.

I guess since I never before needed to change the defaults in that dialog, I automatically skipped it ...

Answer (score -1):

You can open history of the file and then you can show annotation on specific revision using context menu in history view.

Comment: That doesn't change the "To Revision" setting in the "Show annotation" dialog. Unless I change that setting, the newer commit is still reported (I agree it's not intuitive, but it's the way my subclipse works...)